# python subprocess to ffmpeg/ffprobe errors

Tags: python, video-sequence-editor, video, command-line

i'm having difficulties on an addon to help importing and organizing files in the VSE timeline. Basically, i want a little function to retrieve media informations, and return them. I found a lot of piece of code to do that online, but they all returned same kind of errors... Here's my code function :

```
import bpy
import subprocess
import shlex
import json

# function to find the resolution of the input video file
def findVideoMetada(pathToInputVideo):
    ffpath="C:\\Program Files\\ffmpeg-3.3.1-win64-static\\bin\\ffprobe.exe"

    cmd = ffpath+" -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams"
    args = shlex.split(cmd)
    args.append(pathToInputVideo)
    # run the ffprobe process, decode stdout into utf-8 & convert to JSON
    ffprobeOutput = subprocess.check_output(args).decode('utf-8')
    ffprobeOutput = json.loads(ffprobeOutput)

    # prints all the metadata available:
    import pprint
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
    pp.pprint(ffprobeOutput)

    # for example, find height and width
    height = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['height']
    width = ffprobeOutput['streams'][0]['width']

    print(height, width)
    return height, width

file="C:\\Users\\tonton\\Documents\\TAF\\CODE\\work Blender Edit\\test sequence\\test_002.JPG"
print(findVideoMetada(file))
```

And here's a screenshot of the error, 
[image: the error]
i tried to put raw strings, to do several things to avoid spaces in the cmd launched by the subprocess, but it doesn't work...

Any idea about a solution ? :) 
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Don't use shlex, just create a list of strings for your command. That'll work fine with spaces and everything. Also using a JPEG file to test a video metadata function is a bit strange.

Comment: thks for your answer ! yep i already tested with simple string with spaces... but no more success. And agreed it's a bit strange, but to get resolution, it works fine (i tested it in regular command line). But same error is raised with video file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine on my machine (Win10, Blender 2.79, ffmpeg 3.2):

```
import bpy
import json
import subprocess

def find_video_metadata(video_path: str) -> (int, int):
    """Find the resolution of the input video file."""

    ffpath = r"C:\cygwin64\home\Sybren\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe"

    args = [ffpath] + "-v quiet -print_format json -show_streams".split() + [video_path]

    # run the ffprobe process, decode stdout into utf-8 & convert to JSON
    ffout = subprocess.check_output(args).decode('utf-8')
    ffinfo = json.loads(ffout)

    # prints all the metadata available:
    import pprint
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
    pp.pprint(ffinfo)

    # for example, find height and width
    height = ffinfo['streams'][0]['height']
    width = ffinfo['streams'][0]['width']

    print(height, width)
    return height, width

fname = r"A:\RIP\prooi\title03.mkv"
print(find_video_metadata(fname))
```

I've changed a few things:

- Not used `shlex` to parse the string we construct ourselves. Since you didn't quote the filenames containing the space, my bet is that `shlex` couldn't split it properly. By avoiding this altogether and constructing the argument list explicitly, it just works.
- Using 'raw' strings using the `r""` prefix avoids having to double every backslash.
- I like using different names for different things. I split the doubly-used `ffprobeOutput` name into `ffout` (which is a bytes object) and `ffinfo` (which is a dict).
- Not overriding the built-in name `file`.
- Using PEP8 for naming (so no camel case for function names and local variable names).
- I added type declarations to the function.
- Turned the comment into a docstring, and removed the "function to" bit of it; the "def" keyword already indicates that it's a function, so there is no need to repeat that.

Comment: perfect, works like a charm, thk you very much sir ! :)